# Joining two tables based on most relevant prefix

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say I have the following tables:

Table 1:

```
| url           |  value   |
| google.com    |    1     |
| google.com/s1 |    2     |
```

Table 2:

```
| item_url              |   item_value    |
| google.com/example    |       3         |
| google.com/s1/example |       4         |
```

I want to join these two tables such that items with be joined with their corresponding urls in t1, The problem is that the naive approach:

```
select * from t1,t2 where STARTS_WITH(t2.item_url, t1.url)
```

Will cause: *google.com/s1/example* to be joined with both of the values in the first table. Is there a nice clean way to join the tables such that the most 'specific' (Longest prefix?) will be chosen?

The expected output I need is:

```
| item_url              |   url           |       value
| google.com/example    | google.com      |         1
| google.com/s1/example | google.com/s1   |         2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you direct us to MySQL's STARTS_WITH function in the manual. It's new to me.

Comment: Which is the *the most 'specific' (Longest prefix?)* for `google.com` to be joined with? Post your expected results.

Comment: It's actually not related to MySQL. Didn't notice the tag.

Comment: Also added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the longest match.  In BigQuery one approach uses aggregation:

```
with t1 as (
      select 'google.com' as url, 1 as value union all
      select 'google.com/s1', 2
     ),
     t2 as (
      select 'google.com/example' as item_url, 3 as item_value union all
      select 'google.com/s1/example', 4
     )
select t2.item_url, t2.item_value, array_agg(t1 order by length(t1.url) desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*
from t1 JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.item_url like concat(t1.url, '%')
group by t2.item_url, t2.item_value;
```

A more traditional approach uses `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t12.* EXCEPT (seqnum)
FROM (SELECT t2.*, t1.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.item_url, t2.item_value order by length(t1.url) desc) as seqnum
      from t1 JOIN
           t2
           ON t2.item_url like concat(t1.url, '%')
     ) t12
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

And a correlated subquery can also be used:

```
SELECT t2.*,
       (SELECT t1
        FROM t1
        WHERE t2.item_url LIKE CONCAT(t1.url, '%')
        ORDER BY LENGTH(t1.url) DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ).*
FROM t2;
```

Note that these examples return all columns from `t1`, not just the value.  You can, of course, tweak them to only return one column if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables using the operator `LIKE` in the `ON` clause and `group by table1.url, table1.value`. 
Then you need the minimum `table2.item_url` from the result:

```
select min(t2.item_url) item_url, t1.url, t1.value 
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t2.item_url like concat(t1.url, '%')
group by t1.url, t1.value
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d04146ed0c66a89c7ceaa405a6be46e3).
Results:

```
item_url              | url           | value
google.com/example    | google.com    |     1
google.com/s1/example | google.com/s1 |     2
```